# Helper function of a controller does not return anything

Tags: javascript, controller, sencha-touch-2

I have a function in my map controller to convert an address to a google.maps.latlng and I want to return this value, but my function doesn't return anything. I think thats because the values change inside another function, but I can't figure out how to solve this.

```
addressToLatLng: function(address) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(), lat, lng, latlng;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            console.log(latlng); // will give me the object in the log
        }
    });
    return latlng; // nothing happens
},
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the `geocode` call is asynchronous, so you are trying to return the value before it exists.

You can use a callback for the caller to get the value when it arrives:

```
addressToLatLng: function(address, callback) {
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder(), lat, lng, latlng;
    geocoder.geocode({ 'address': address }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            lat = results[0].geometry.location.lat();
            lng = results[0].geometry.location.lng();
            latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
            callback(latlng);
        }
    });
},
```

Usage:

```
yourController.addressToLatLng(address, function(latlng){
  console.log(latlng);
});
```

Comment: Firstofall thanks! The code works fine but doesnt solve my problem. I want to use the latlng outside the callback. E.g.
a1 = this.addressToLatLng(address1) //a1 gets the value/object of latlng
a2 = this.addressToLatLng(address2)
google.maps.geometry.spherical.computeDistanceBetween(a1, a2)

Comment: @user3102211: To do that you would need a time machine, so that you could go to the future and get the value before it exists. It's when the callback is called that the value is available to you for the first time, before that you can't get it. You can return a promise from the method, but that is only a way to put the callback in an object that you can return, you still have to get the value out of the promise asynchronously.

Comment: well is there any other possibility to get the distances from your current location to some addresses of a list (without having the lat/lng, because its easy when those are already given)?

Comment: @user3102211: You don't need another way, just do the call in the callback, and use the result of the next call in its callback.